# User cannot map share from system in another AD Domain

Tags: windows, windows-7, network-share, share

In domain B we have a server, with the share "Company$". In domain A we have users that are mapping the share to a drive letter. One of my users, we'll call him "Joe", cannot mount that share. When he attempts it, including using credentials in domain B, his workstation simply sits for a minute or two "Attempting to connect to...", and then the credentials dialog box comes back.

I should note that the difference between Joe and other users in domain A is that Joe already has some folders from the server mapped onto his machine. AND, because he forgot his password, I changed it for him. So he has shares mapped using his old password, and now we want to map a share using his new password.

Is there an obvious problem I'm missing here? I'm a Linux administrator by experience, so this is new territory for me.

We have Windows 7 SP1... is this a bug, or do I just not understand Windows shares? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a domain trust established? or did you setup credentials on both domains?

Comment: Credentials on both domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to use the credentials it already knows about to map the drive. Instead of mapping a new share with the new password, you should disconnect the shares with a bad password, and reconnect with the new one. You'll want to disconnect all drive using the old credentials.

you can do something like:

```
net use /d <Drive_letter>
net use /user:<DOMIAN\User> <Drive_Letter> <UNC>
```

If you have a lot of drives that need to be redone you can do `net use /d *` to remove all mapped drives at once. Then reconnect them. Or do it via the GUI.

After you unmap the drives you'll want to go into ADUC and make sure the account isn't locked.

Comment: I suspect that's true. But if so, why doesn't Windows just take the credentials it's given to it? We tell it to use a different set of credentials... doesn't it just go ahead with those, or does it try to get tricky because it already knows it has cached credentials by that user name in the remote domain?

Comment: It's trying to be helpful and use the cached credentials until they expire. It's an old issue ... *shrug*